# how to comprehend prepositions at the end of sentences

Tags: sentence-structure, questions

Today I have very difficult question for you. Firstly, I am Russian-speaking man.

Let's have some question like "Who are you waiting for?" or 
"Who are they with?" or "Which restaurant should we eat at?" etc... That is, question with preposition at the end of question.

Let's take this one: "Who are they with?"
In Russian it has next order of words: "With who they are?"

And hence I don't understand how you can say in your order...
Please explain to me, how do you can catch "with" at the end???

For me, meanings of two next sentences are very different:

> "Who are they?"
>   "Who are they with?"

How do you understand that preposition "with" in addition to the whole sentence "Who are they"?

Do you wait till the whole sentence is pronounced to understand it correctly, or you guess what is at the end?

Comment: Unless someone is speaking very slowly, "Who are they with" comes pretty quickly and is idiomatic for the more correct "who is with them" or stuffy-formal "with whom are they (fill in with appropriate word..."travelling", "dining", "speaking", etc.)."  Bearing in mind the context of the conversation, you'll probably get used to hearing it and not get confused and think someone is asking "Who are they..." instead of "Who are they with".

Comment: You say "*With who they are?*" in Russian. You can say "With whom are they?" in English. And *"At which restaurant should we eat?*" And "*For whom are you waiting?*" No problem.

Comment: @KristinaLopez I still think that final prepositions do appear awkward and untidy and would always do my best to avoid them in any formal register. Informally I have no hesitation is suggesting "For whom are you waiting", and even more "In which restaurant should we eat". But I am an Englishman of a certain age and find it hard to depart from what was insisted to me was correct, in my youth.

Comment: The stressed syllables change depending on what's coming:  "who are they?" would usually be stressed on 'they', but "who are they with?" would have an unstressed 'they' and a stressed 'with'.

Comment: @Hellion Yes, when the preposition is the one you need to stress, then I feel more comfortable in putting it - perhaps of necessity - at the end.

Comment: I understand, @WS2, while I do my very best to avoid the dangling preposition in writing because it's just THERE for everyone to see...forever, I am guilty of using it in casual speech. :-\

Comment: Stranded preps are perfectly normal and acceptable. No one says "For whom are you waiting"; that's ridiculous. Just about everyone says "Who are you waiting for".

Comment: The objection that you have to wait for the end of the sentence to be sure of the meaning is silly.  Even if you asked "For whom are you waiting?", you'd still have to wait for the word "waiting" to be sure what was being asked.  Similarly, even in the highly unlikely event that you asked "with whom are they?", you would need to hear the word "they" (and the lack of a gerund-participle after it) to be sure of the question.

Comment: @WS2 And yet stranded prepositions are a lot more natural and less awkward than preposed ones in many cases. “For whom are you waiting?” is highly stilted and not at all natural to most people; “About what are you talking?” is borderline ungrammatical to me; and “For what did you do that?” is presumably quite bizarre to everyone. And then there are cases where final prepositions are quite unavoidable: “He hates being shouted at”, “I’m fed up”, “Don’t give in!”, etc. It’s not even **possible** to avoid final prepositions there.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Well none of those are the ones I proposed. If it sounds as though it might be "stilted" then I don't say it. (though stiltedness, like beauty, I suspect is in the eye of the beholder). It is fashionable to say that Dryden's rule is fatuous, but I've passed the point in life where I am required to be slave to fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I put the vase in the living room.
>   -- What did you put it **on**?

Native speakers have no problem understanding that **on** is to be taken in combination with **what** and **put**.  It is natural in English for prepositions to appear at the tail-end of an interrogative.

We can ask the same question in this manner:

> On what [thing] did you put the vase?

Answer (score 3):

> For me, meanings of two next sentences are very different: "Who are they?" "Who are they with?"

In this scenario, context matters quite a bit. Let's take this example:

> Ashley and John are there.

*Who are they?* implies that the speaker does not know who Ashley and John are.

*Who are they with?* implies that the speaker does know who Ashley and John are and that the speaker is instead interested in who **else** is there.

Usually, in such a conversation, there will be context before the question "Who are they with?" is proposed -- enough so that the *they* in the sentence is well-established. Compare:

> Nick is with some people at the bar.
>
> Nick is with Ashley and John at the bar.

In the first scenario, the subject of the sentence -- the *some people* -- has not been identified, so the question "Who are they?" makes sense. In the second scenario, the fact that every person in the sentence has been named implies that the audience knows who Nick, Ashley, and John are, so the question "Who are they?" makes less sense to ask, and instead "Who are they with?" makes more sense.

In fact, if I were to say "Nick is with Ashley and John at the bar" to someone who I thought knew all three people, and their response was "Who are they?", it would be jarring, and my response would likely be "Oh, have you not met them?".

> Do you wait till the whole sentence is pronounced to understand it correctly, or you guess what is at the end?

In summary (and to answer this question), the questions "Who are they?" and "Who are they with?" are used in different contexts, and though people will listen to the entire sentence, the speaker is already anticipating which of the two questions is more likely.